# Primary File Organization in DBMS - Files of ordered records (sorted files)

Tags: database-theory, databases, filesystems, storage

"Fundamental of Database Systems", 3rd ed. by Elmasri and Navathe, page 136 says:

"We can physically order the records of a file on disk based on the values of one of their fields [...]"

How could this "physical ordering" possibly enforced, especially with regard to fragmentation? Most databases use system calls to store their data in the file system of the OS, only very few are capable of doing raw i/o.

Comment: (the 3rd ed seems to be from 2000, when *disc* meant *glass platters rotating fast enough to float at least one giant MR head per surface*. And possibly still *concentric tracks* instead of *one spiral per surface*. (And seven editions don't say any given paragraph has been reviewed since first published.))

Comment: (For better or worse, the magnetic domains of a multi-loop bubble memory could be made to move around somewhat independently.)

Comment: @greybeard Unfortunately, this sentence can still be found in the 7th edition (chapter 16.7 on page 598).